# Unfocus on click on datepicker (3rd click should open it also)

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I have a datepicker configured pretty straight forward, but the third click on this datepicker is not opening it unless you unfocus the datepicker by clicking somewhere else.
So, this is happening at the moment:

- First click on datepicker: Opens the datepicker
- Second click on datepicker: Closes the datepicker
- Third click on datepicker: Does nothing (but should open the datepicker again).

I tried using onClose and clear the focus by using element.blur() but this only triggers when I don't click directly onto the input field (which is exactly the case I wanted to fix).

```
$( "#cmpz_start" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy', minDate: 0, autoclose: true, 
    beforeShowDay: 
        function(date) {
            // get disabled dates and check them
            var disabled = check_date(date, cmpz_disabled_dates);
            return disabled;
        }, 
    onClose: 
        function()  {
            this.blur();
        }
});
```

You can see the above datepicker on this page: [www.vanberry.de](https://vanberry.de)
But I disabled the blur() because it's not working.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should log the `this` in your `onClose()` Callback function.
I think it isn't a jQuery Object so it doesn't know the `blur()` function.
You should change it to `$(this).blur();`

You could also add a parameter to the Callback function, in this parameter the target should be present. Lets assume you call your paramter `e`, you could write `$(e.target).blur();`

Comment: "this" works also standalone, thanks for your comment! I thought my code would not work, but actually it's working "too good". With the code above, each click blurs the element and opens the datepicker right away. So, I should make a click counter and only blur on uneven click counts. Or am I thinking too complicated